# Can I install bumblebee and also TLP?

Tags: 14.04, bumblebee, tlp

I have a question about if I can install bumblebee and also TLP or I have to install just one of them. I think both of them have the same functions but I'm not very sure. I have an ASUS q552  with nvidia graphics Geforce 940M and also intel graphics with i7 processor.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not install bumblebee, it was replaced by nvidia-prime to switch between graphics,
nvidia-prime should have been installed automatically when you installed the NVIDIA drivers.
In case this did not happen, you can install nvidia-prime by opening a terminal and executing :

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```

TLP is something completely different - it is a tool you can use to optimize power consumption.
So you can install both tools, nvidia-prime to switch between graphics and TLP to tweak power.
Switch between the intel and NVIDIA graphics with NVIDIA X Server Settings -> PRIME Profiles.

Comment: Thank you cl-netbox, that help me to know about that. Unfortunately I had installed bumblebee I don't know if is a good idea to uninstall it now. But I'm going to install tlp and thermald, the temperature of my pc is 60 oC when I use only chrome and play youtube videos

Comment: @Anargu : You're welcome - you can safely remove bumblebee -> sudo apt-get purge bumblebee - enjoy ubuntu experience ! :)