# Laptop gets too hot

Tags: bumblebee

My laptop has Intel (integrated) and Nvidia graphic cards. I have installed bumblebee.
But laptop is still getting too hot. 
How can I check if I have done everything correctly?

Comment: Did you install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: You said nothing about how long you use your laptop, what have been there before, how long you are seeing this issue.
Maybe your device requires cooler exchange or dust cleaning.

Comment: @Pilot6 I installed Nvidia drivers before bumblebee. And changed the active video driver using Prime. And then I installed bumblebee.

Comment: You can't use bumblebee and prime at the same time.

Comment: @Gryu The issue has been there from beginning. I did everything I found on internet about this issue. But I'm new to ubuntu and I don't know if I have done things correctly or not. Bumblebee is supposed to turn off the nvidia device, right? Is there anyway to check that if the device is off or on?

Comment: @Pilot6 so I should uninstall the nvidia driver and only keep bumblebee?

Comment: I would suggest to remove bumblebee, keep Nvidia driver and switch to Intel in prime.

Comment: Sometimes raising the laptop up bit from a surface can help, place small ~1/2inch spacers at the four corners or even get a cheap laptop cooler.  Making sure inside of laptop is clean is number one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this answer bumblebee no longer is the recommended option: https://askubuntu.com/a/735251/1029870

In addition to this I suggest you install TLP and HES. [TLP](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/03/linux-battery-optimization-tool-tlp-12.html) is a set of tools that helps with Laptop hardware, especially with things like spinning fans and thermal management and the [HWE Stack (Hardware Enablement Stack)](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-hwe-kernel/) gives you access to the newest drivers and a more recent Kernel.

To install tlp run:

```
sudo apt install tlp tlp-rdw
```

and after that:

```
sudo tlp start
```

To install HWE Stack:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

Comment: It seems `tlp` doesn't do anything if laptop is charging. I ran `sudo tlp true` to enable power saving mode explicitly.